# Always show 2 decimal places in input type number

Tags: html

I have `<input type="number" value="0.00" min="0.00" max="1.00" step="0.05">` but when it reaches to 0.1 or 0.2 or 0.3 etc. I need to show 0.10 instead of 0.1, 1.00 instead of 1

I tried `pattern="^\d+(\.|\,)\d{2}$"` attribute but it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `onchange` event and use `toFixed(2)`

```html
<input type="number" onchange="(function(el){el.value=parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);})(this)" value="0.00" min="0.00" max="1.00" step="0.05">
```

Comment: Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) to the rescue

Answer (score 3):

```js
function onInput(event) {
  let value = parseFloat(event.value);
  if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
    document.getElementById('input-1').value = "0.00";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('input-1').value = value.toFixed(2);
  }              
}
```

```html
<input id="input-1" type="number" min="0.00" max="1.00" step="0.05" oninput="onInput(this)" value="0.00" />
```

Comment: this one is even better since it called on every value alteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use step `0.01` instead of `0.05` and add eventListener on value change to force fixed decimal:

```js
var numberElement = document.querySelector('.number-decimal');
numberElement.addEventListener('change',alterNumber);

function alterNumber(event){
var el = event.target;
var elValue = el.value;
el.value = parseFloat(elValue).toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<input class="number-decimal" type="number" value="0.00" min="0.00" max="1.00" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00">
```